# How can I display a splash screen for a longer period of time than the default time on an iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiimageview, splash-screen

I have try so many way in display the splash screen for a longer period of time but i did't get perfect solution,please help me out.

Comment: According to the Apple Human Interface Guidelines document, you aren't supposed to have a splash page.

Comment: "so many way" -> What ways.. show us.

Comment: @inafziger strange when they provide the Default.PNG functionality

Comment: dear friend, According to the Apple Human Interface Guidelines document, you can have a splash screen but you aren't supposed to adjust its delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `AppDelegate.m` file just define splashView as a `UIImageView` and then in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method write this type of code...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:iphoneFrame];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadViewIphone) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];// define time which you want..
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and in loadViewIphone method just remove this splashView like bellow

```
-(void)loadViewIphone 
{
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;// or any viewontroller instead of tabbarController
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // this bellow code is used for transactionaly swap splashscreen to our viewcontroller..
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];

}
```

Comment: hi, have tried this link http://michael.burford.net/2008/11/fading-defaultpng-when-iphone-app.html

Comment: yes i tried all the 3 ways .. But even i am getting the image... Those all the answers are working but the first image apppears @Paras Joshi