# I am getting 2 different images in place of splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am getting an different image at the start of the app like a splash screen then i am getting my actual image that i placed in coding.
I placed the splash screen with the following code in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    LoginViewController *vc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.loginNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([userDefaults valueForKey:@"UserName"] &&[userDefaults valueForKey:@"Password"])
    {
        vc.username=[userDefaults valueForKey:@"UserName"];
        vc.password=[userDefaults valueForKey:@"Password"];
        vc.autoLogin=YES;
        [vc loginSelectorMethod];
    }
    
    else
    {
        [self.window addSubview:self.loginNav.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splashscreen.png"];
    [window addSubview:splashView];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0]; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    NSLog(@"Registering for remote notifications"); 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    
    return YES;
}
```

Before the splash screen appears , the "Arrow.png" image appears then my splash screen appers.
If i delete the "Arrow.png" then in place of that image another images appears i.e., "aboutus.png" like that it continues.

I searched in my project for the "Arrow.png" it only appears once in my whole project in the coding.

Comment: sorry i can't get your question clearly ... so what you want?? ...u mean u need first your flash screen is display ?? then after other ??

Comment: @Babul see my this answer for splashscreen.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454144/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-a-longer-period-of-time-than-the-default-t/13454189#13454189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you add subiview as a tabbar like bellow..

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

after you add loginview like bellow..

```
[self.window addSubview:self.loginNav.view];
```

and after that you add splashscreen like bellow..

```
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splashscreen.png"];
    [window addSubview:splashView];
```

So this is the problem that you seen more then screen instead of splashscreen.

use bellow code...

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{   
   splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splashscreen.png"];
    [window addSubview:splashView];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0]; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    NSLog(@"Registering for remote notifications"); 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    return YES;
}
```

and in `removeSplash` method add this view as a subview of window like bellow..

```
-(void)removeSplash{
[splashView removeFromSuperView];
LoginViewController *vc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.loginNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([userDefaults valueForKey:@"UserName"] &&[userDefaults valueForKey:@"Password"])
    {
        vc.username=[userDefaults valueForKey:@"UserName"];
        vc.password=[userDefaults valueForKey:@"Password"];
        vc.autoLogin=YES;
        [vc loginSelectorMethod];
    }

    else
    {
        [self.window addSubview:self.loginNav.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Babul try my this answer for splashscreen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454144/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-a-longer-period-of-time-than-the-default-t/13454189#13454189

Comment: i did as u said.. But now i got another image i.e., (info.png) instead of "Arrow.png"  @Paras Joshi

Comment: hey see my answer from i given link and see removbe or comment your code of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and use only mine code and intruction from that link try this

Comment: yes.. i used ur code only.. see this link once what i did  pastie.org/5660782 @Paras Joshi

Comment: @Babul just comment whole code and use only my code from that link and also  comment [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    NSLog(@"Registering for remote notifications"); 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
 this 3 line just for testing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22512/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-babul)

Comment: @Babul from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454144/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-a-longer-period-of-time-than-the-default-t/13454189#13454189

Comment: yes i tried all the 3 ways .. But even i am getting the image... Those all the answers are working but the first image apppears @Paras Joshi

Comment: @Babul what you mean that ?? means whats the problem here i not got it dude?? :(

Comment: still i am getting that image before my splash screen  @Paras Joshi

Comment: @Babul hey just see do this thing.. just give your image name with Default.png and store it in your project.. and then also use this name in splashscreen also try this now

Comment: i did like this also.. But no result @ Paras Joshi

Comment: @Babul click on this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22512/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-babul

Answer (score 2):

Have you set any Launch image in ur project setting or have you put any image named "Default.png" in your project bundle this kind of image get detect by OS automatically while launch our app please check this 2 points.

edit:-

Than the problem is conflict in `TabBar` & LoginView & splaceImage.

For this do below stuff I thing this resolve your double image issue.

First, put below code in your `DidFinishLaunching()` method

> //Delay second that how much time u show your splace image
> int64_t delayInSeconds = 5.0;

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Do need Full like Add Login View or Add TabbBar 
    
    //Remove SplaceImageView From Window 
});

splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait~ipad.png"];
[self.window addSubview:splashView];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
return YES;
```

and also one more thing add default splace image like

for iPhone Portrait Default.png.
for iPad, Portrait Default-Portrait~ipad.png
follow as apple document for default image and then check.

Comment: yes.. i did like that also but i did not get result  @Dhanesh

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary 

    *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        
        self.sql_ = [SQLDb initEngine];
        
        
        [self setupControllers]; /// Set up Yor ToolBar Controller
        
        self.hvController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.hvController;
        
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        
        [self setupSplash];
    
       return YES;
    }
    
    -(void) setupSplash
    {
        self.imvSplash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
        
        if( IS_IPHONE_5 )
            [self.imvSplash setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"]];
        else
            [self.imvSplash setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"]];
        
        [self.window addSubview: self.imvSplash];
        
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f     target:self selector:@selector(hideSplash:) userInfo:nil   repeats:NO];
    }
    
    - (void)hideSplash:(NSTimer *)theTimer
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                              delay:0.1
                                           options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                     animations:^{
                                                            self.imvSplash.alpha = 0.0;
                                                            self.ngNavigationController.view.alpha = 1.0;
                                                        }
                                                        completion:^(BOOL finished)
                                                        {
                                                             //[self.ngController setupImageAction];
                                                             [self.imvSplash removeFromSuperview];
                                                         }];
    }
```